# Conditional Formatting in Tikz & How to work mathematically with variables

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

[image]Here's a MWE of a simple numberline I've generated wherein I use `\ifthenelse` from the `xifthen` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw[->] (-5.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node [below] {$\mathbb{R}$};

  \foreach \x in {-5,...,5}
    \ifthenelse{\x = 2 \OR \x=4}{\draw (\x,0.1) -- (\x,-0.1) node [below,red] {\x}}{\draw (\x,0.1) -- (\x,-0.1) node [below,black] {\x}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How can I do something simple like make all the even numbers red with a simple formula? Or make all multiples of 5 larger and in bold/blue.  Can Tikz do something like this?

Comment: You can use things like `\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-5.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node [below] {$\mathbb{R}$};
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xeval using int(2*\x),evaluate=\x as \xevalo using int(2*\x+1)] in {-2,...,2}
{
   \draw ({int(2*\x)},0.1) -- ({int(2*\x)},-0.1) node [below,red] {\xeval};
   \draw (\xevalo,0.1) -- (\xevalo,-0.1) node [below,blue] {\xevalo};
}
\end{tikzpicture}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Much more verbose than the other answers, but allows for the separation of almost every bit of formatting from the drawing code, and the use of the `node contents` key allows different typesetting of the numbers.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcount\tikzcount
\tikzset{%
  number/.code={%
    \tikzset{every number/.try=#1}%
    \ifodd#1\relax
      \tikzset{every odd number/.try=#1}%
    \else
      \tikzset{every even number/.try=#1}%
    \fi%
    \tikzset{execute for this number/.try=#1, number #1/.try=#1}%
  },
  execute for this number/.code={},
  number divisible by/.style args={#1 then #2}{%
    execute for this number/.append code={%
      \tikzcount=##1
      \divide\tikzcount by #1
      \multiply\tikzcount by #1
      \ifnum\tikzcount=##1 \tikzset{#2}\fi%
    }%
  }  
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  every number/.style={below=.333em, node contents=#1},
  every odd number/.style={red},
  every even number/.style={blue, node contents=$#1$},
  number divisible by=5 then {purple},
  number divisible by=3 then {font=\bfseries, blue},
  number 0/.style={shape=circle, fill=red!20, text=black},
  number -4/.style={xslant=0.25, fill=blue!20}
]
\draw[->] (-5.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node [below] {$\mathbb{R}$};
\foreach \x in {-5,...,5}
  \draw (\x,0.1) -- (\x,-0.1) (\x,0) node [number=\x];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this nearly doesn't seem like the code I'm used to at all!  Starting with `\tikzset{%
  number/.code={% ...`

Where can I learn this sub-language?

Comment: There's enough interest; and, judging by the range of responses, enough room for everyone to learn, that I will leave the question open for a day or so longer.

Comment: @pefmath `\tikzset` is part of tikz's (and pgf) key-value management system. It is described in the manual in the section 'Key Management'. Whenever you specify a color or an arrow head, etc., in a tikz command (e.g., `\draw [red, ->] (0,0) -- (1,1);`) you are implicitly using this key-management system.

Comment: @ Mark,  Would love a link,  It doesn't seem to be in the one I was using (http://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) .

Comment: @pefmath Try [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use `evaluate <variable> as <macro> using <formula>`. A simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-5.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node [below] {$\mathbb{R}$};
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xeval using int(2*\x),evaluate=\x as \xevalo using int(2*\x+1)] in {-2,...,2}
{
   \draw (\xeval,0.1) -- (\xeval,-0.1) node [below,red] {$\xeval$};
   \draw (\xevalo,0.1) -- (\xevalo,-0.1) node [below,blue,font=\Huge] {$\xevalo$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or also something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-5.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node [below] {$\mathbb{R}$};
\foreach \x  in {-5,...,5}
{ 
  \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\x,5))} 
  \ifnum0=\pgfmathresult\relax
     \draw (\x,0.1) -- (\x,-0.1) node [below,blue,font=\Huge] {$\x$};
   \else  
     \draw (\x,0.1) -- (\x,-0.1) node [font=\footnotesize,below,fill=red!20,circle,minimum size=2em] {$\x$};
  \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about turning the wrong hyphens into minus signs?

Comment: @egreg That would be a good thing, indeed! Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set the colour as part of the calculation within the loop:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[big blue/.style={font=\bfseries\Large, blue}]

  \draw[->] (-5.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node [below] {$\mathbb{R}$};

  \foreach \x in {-5,...,5}
  {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ncol{iseven(\x) ? "red": "black"}
    \draw (\x,0.1) -- (\x,-0.1) node [below,\ncol] {\x};
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ncol{( mod(\x,5) == 0 ) ? "big blue": "black"}
    \draw (\x,-1.1) -- (\x,-1.1) node [below,\ncol] {\x};
  }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: looped calculations]

Comment: You've used `iseven`,  under which section in the manual the list of all functions?

Comment: @CroCo VIII esp. 89